# Possible to add a third color to a 'bar' sparkline?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-sparkline

I have three columns of data that I want to represent with sparklines as a stacked bar chart.

For instance, a row like

```
12  5   1
```

with this formula

```
=SPARKLINE(C2:E2,{"charttype","bar"})
```

shows an image like this: [image: Sparkline chart]

As you can see, the first and third colors are the same. I would like to specify all three colors, so that the first and third colors are different.

Google's SPARKLINE Help docs indicate bar charts set two colors by default; these can be user specified as color1 and color2. They do not provide any instructions for specifying additional colors.

I have tried specifying color1, color2, AND color3, and I have tried specifying lastcolor; neither option alters the third color. I also tried setting just color, then specifying color1 and color2 as a default, to see if Sheets would default to the setting for color for the third color. That did not work either.

Is there a way to set the 3rd color to be different from the first color?

Answer (score 5):

Although it is not documented in [SPARKLINE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en) (Google Docs support)  you can now specify more than 2 colors using the same `color[#]` syntax that is used for the first two colors.

For example, the following formula specifies a different color for each of the 5 bars:

```
=SPARKLINE(
   {1,1,1,1,1},
   {"charttype","bar";
    "color1","blue";  "color2","red"; "color3","pink";
    "color4","green"; "color5","yellow"})
```

[image: Example Sparkline Bar Graph]

Comment: Good catch Karl. I made some edits to improve the answer including a link to the Google support doc.

Comment: I just checked. This works up to color9.

Answer (score 2):

From the question:

> Is there a way to set the 3rd color to be different from the first color?

No, there isn't.

According the the [SPARKLINE official help article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en), the options for a SPARKLINE bar chart are

> For bar charts:
>
> - "max" sets the maximum value along the horizontal axis.
> - "color1" sets the first color used for bars in the chart.
> - "color2" sets the second color used for bars in the chart.
> - "empty" sets how to treat empty cells. Possible corresponding values include: "zero" or "ignore".
> - "nan" sets how to treat cells with non-numeric data. Options are: "convert" and "ignore".
> - "rtl" determines whether or not the chart is rendered right to left. Options are true or false.

As you can see, ther only two possible options for setting bar colors, *color1* and *color2*

Answer (score 1):

You may switch the color by add "a3bc9f" (the color code in double citation mark) to change the color.

Like this: `=SPARKLINE(B4:C4,{"charttype","bar";"color1",if(B4>C4,"#dd7e6b","a3bc9f");"color2",if(C4>B4,"#dd7e6b","a3bc9f")})`

Comment: Ximugu, thanks for this, but it still seems to create only two colors in the chart. My question was "Can you have three colors or more in a 'bar' sparkline?" Sadly, the answer seems to be "No."

Answer (score 0):

You can't add more than two colors to the bar chart. HOWEVER, you can get a similar result with this waterfall of bar charts. Just make the first color white, and make a table of the sum of the previous values. The formula for second bar chart looks like this:

`=ArrayFormula(SPARKLINE($M3:$N3,{"charttype","bar";"max",MAX($D$9:$D$16);"color1","#ffffff";"color2","#93c47d"}))`

[image]